# Swappable Login Form Showing Both Fields on Mobile

Tags: html, css, login-control

I have an issue with my login page, seen here on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKV6d.jpg

Basically it seems to show both sides of the flippable-login, and it should only be showing one side, and when I go to enter text it's flipped as well (so text goes RTL instead of LTR)

On desktop it's normal, seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGXTy.png

JSFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/wgjyzf4m/

Overall a really annoying problem and I have no idea where it comes from, code below

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #6a6f8c;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  font: 600 16px/18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: '';
  display: table
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none
}

.login-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 525px;
  min-height: 670px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khadkamhn/day-01-login-form/master/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .19);
}

.login-html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 90px 70px 50px 70px;
  background: rgba(40, 57, 101, .9);
}

.login-html .sign-in-htm,
.login-html .sign-up-htm {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

.login-html .sign-in,
.login-html .sign-up,
.login-form .group .check {
  display: none;
}

.login-html .tab,
.login-form .group .label,
.login-form .group .button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.login-html .tab {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.login-html .sign-in:checked+.tab,
.login-html .sign-up:checked+.tab {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #1161ee;
}

.login-form {
  min-height: 345px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.login-form .group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.login-form .group .label,
.login-form .group .input,
.login-form .group .button {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.login-form .group .input,
.login-form .group .button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.login-form .group input[data-type="password"] {
  text-security: circle;
  -webkit-text-security: circle;
}

.login-form .group .label {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.login-form .group .button {
  background: #1161ee;
}

.login-form .group label .icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.login-form .group label .icon:before,
.login-form .group label .icon:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.login-form .group label .icon:before {
  left: 3px;
  width: 5px;
  bottom: 6px;
  transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
}

.login-form .group label .icon:after {
  top: 6px;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(0) rotate(0);
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label {
  color: #fff;
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label .icon {
  background: #1161ee;
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label .icon:before {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg);
}

.login-form .group .check:checked+label .icon:after {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
}

.login-html .sign-in:checked+.tab+.sign-up+.tab+.login-form .sign-in-htm {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.login-html .sign-up:checked+.tab+.login-form .sign-up-htm {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.hr {
  height: 2px;
  margin: 60px 0 50px 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.foot-lnk {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-wrap">
  <div class="login-html">
    <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Sign In</label>
    <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
    <div class="login-form">
      <form class="sign-in-htm" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="group">
          <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
          <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
          <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input id="check" type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
          <label for="check"><span class="icon"></span> Keep me Signed in</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign In">
        </div>
        <div class="hr"></div>
        <div class="foot-lnk">
          <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" class="sign-up-htm">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="group">
          <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
          <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
          <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <label for="pass" class="label">Repeat Password</label>
          <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <label for="pass" class="label">Email Address</label>
          <input id="pass" type="text" class="input">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up">
        </div>
        <div class="hr"></div>
        <div class="foot-lnk">
          <label for="tab-1">Already Member?</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your issue. The thing is **Firefox 10+ and IE 10+** support `backface-visibility` with no prefix. **Opera (post Blink, 15+), Chrome, Safari, iOS, and Android** all need `-webkit-backface-visibility`.

So, try to insert `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` and see it should work.

```
.login-html .sign-in-htm,
.login-html .sign-up-htm {          
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  color:#6a6f8c;
  background:#c8c8c8;
  font:600 16px/18px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}
*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}
.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before{content:'';display:table}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;display:block}
a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none}

.login-wrap{
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:525px;
  min-height:670px;
  position:relative;
  background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khadkamhn/day-01-login-form/master/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
  box-shadow:0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
}
.login-html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  padding:90px 70px 50px 70px;
  background:rgba(40,57,101,.9);
}
.login-html .sign-in-htm,
.login-html .sign-up-htm{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  transition:all .4s linear;
}
.login-html .sign-in,
.login-html .sign-up,
.login-form .group .check{
  display:none;
}
.login-html .tab,
.login-form .group .label,
.login-form .group .button{
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
.login-html .tab{
  font-size:22px;
  margin-right:15px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin:0 15px 10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
}
.login-html .sign-in:checked + .tab,
.login-html .sign-up:checked + .tab{
  color:#fff;
  border-color:#1161ee;
}
.login-form{
  min-height:345px;
  position:relative;
  perspective:1000px;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.login-form .group{
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.login-form .group .label,
.login-form .group .input,
.login-form .group .button{
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  display:block;
}
.login-form .group .input,
.login-form .group .button{
  border:none;
  padding:15px 20px;
  border-radius:25px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.login-form .group input[data-type="password"]{
  text-security:circle;
  -webkit-text-security:circle;
}
.login-form .group .label{
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:12px;
}
.login-form .group .button{
  background:#1161ee;
}
.login-form .group label .icon{
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius:2px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.login-form .group label .icon:before,
.login-form .group label .icon:after{
  content:'';
  width:10px;
  height:2px;
  background:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  transition:all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.login-form .group label .icon:before{
  left:3px;
  width:5px;
  bottom:6px;
  transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
}
.login-form .group label .icon:after{
  top:6px;
  right:0;
  transform:scale(0) rotate(0);
}
.login-form .group .check:checked + label{
  color:#fff;
}
.login-form .group .check:checked + label .icon{
  background:#1161ee;
}
.login-form .group .check:checked + label .icon:before{
  transform:scale(1) rotate(45deg);
}
.login-form .group .check:checked + label .icon:after{
  transform:scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
}
.login-html .sign-in:checked + .tab + .sign-up + .tab + .login-form .sign-in-htm{
  transform:rotate(0);
}
.login-html .sign-up:checked + .tab + .login-form .sign-up-htm{
  transform:rotate(0);
}

.hr{
  height:2px;
  margin:60px 0 50px 0;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.foot-lnk{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-wrap">
    <div class="login-html">
      <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label for="tab-1" class="tab">Sign In</label>
      <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
      <div class="login-form">
        <form class="sign-in-htm" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
            <div class="group">
              <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
              <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
              <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <input id="check" type="checkbox" class="check" checked>
              <label for="check"><span class="icon"></span> Keep me Signed in</label>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign In">
            </div>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div class="foot-lnk">
              <a href="/forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
          </form>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" class="sign-up-htm" >
            <div class="group">
              <label for="user" class="label">Username</label>
              <input id="user" type="text" class="input">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label>
              <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <label for="pass" class="label">Repeat Password</label>
              <input id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <label for="pass" class="label">Email Address</label>
              <input id="pass" type="text" class="input">
            </div>
            <div class="group">
              <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign Up">
            </div>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div class="foot-lnk">
              <label for="tab-1">Already Member?</label>
              </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're a godsend, thank you so much, never would have found that CSS option without you pointing it out